# Proving that $\cos x \cot^2x$ and $(\csc x \cot x)\cdot(-\cos x)$ are equivalent

Tags: trigonometry

> I have to prove that 
>   $$\cos x \cot^2x \quad\text{and}\quad(\csc x \cot x)\cdot(-\cos x)$$
>   are equivalent.

When I set $x=10$, and I calculate the result with a scientific calculator, I get the same result.

But how do I prove they are equivalent by using trigonometric properties?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What do you get when you substitute the definitions of $\cot x$ and $\csc x$?

Comment: Are you really sure that the result is the same for $x=10$?

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. For $0<x<\pi /2$ the first one is positive and second one is negative.